# Is this ancient explosive mixture mentioned in the Apocrypha plausible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, explosives

I understand that religious discussion is not wanted here, but it's just the pretext to my question. I recently decided to read the Apocrypha. Sounded interesting. Anyway, when I got to [The Book of Bel and The Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bel_and_the_Dragon), there was this verse, which struck me as particularly interesting:

> 1:27 Then Daniel took pitch, and fat, and hair, and did seethe them together, and made lumps thereof: this he put in the dragon's mouth, and so the dragon burst in sunder and Daniel said, Lo, these are the gods ye worship.

Now, what I'm wondering (and the only reason I'm bringing this up here), is what would this do? It seems to be an extremely early reference to use of explosives, which is fascinating in a purely historical sense, but what sort of material would actually be formed by boiling a mixture of pitch, fat, and hair? Would this have some explosive tendency, as can be interpreted from the passage? I'm a chemistry major, but I haven't even gone through Organic yet, so if any of you know anything about the properties this would (or would not) have, I would greatly appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: I'm certainly not a biblical scholar but, from reading other translations, I believe the idea here wasn't that Daniel put the mixture in the dragon's mouth, upon which the mixture exploded; but rather, that the dragon burst after consuming the mixture (the implication perhaps being that the mixture reacted with the dragon's gastric juices after consumption to produce so much gas that the dragon burst).  I.e., this seems more a reference to a chemical reaction that produces gas than to one that produces an explosion.  I'd recommend checking this on https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll add they probably were familiar with reactions that vigorously produced gas in biblical times--e.g., humans used both vinegar and sodium carbonate since at least 3500 BC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will ask this on Hermeneutics. And just to clarify, is there a process that can explain what happens when the hair, fat, and pitch combined with the dragons gastric juices? You mentioned that in the dragon, it produced so much gas that the dragon burst, I am curious about that.

Comment: Well, I mentioned the *idea* behind it may have been that it produced so much gas the dragon burst.   I'm afraid I can't give you a chemical reaction off the top of my head. My point wasn't to say specifically that a certain chemistry was involved, but rather that the passage may have been motivated by a familiarity with gas-producing chemical reactions rather than a familiarity with explosives.

Comment: There is nothing explosive in a mixture of pitch (long chain alkanes), fat (triglcerides) and hair even in the presence of gastric acid. Deeply indigestible though. perhaps the dragon's gut burst.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer so perhaps exploding is not the right word. But, when you say the dragons gut burst, what does that mean? Like the dragons stomach ripped open as a result of the combination?

Comment: Not explosive but probably a reference to "early thermal weapons" see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_thermal_weapons

Comment: Thank you because this is starting to make alot of sense. and for more clarificaiton, is there like a wesbite or something that can either explain or like a chemical formula that can explain how the hair, pitch, and fat can kill a serpent or at the very least explains how a combination like that can be toxic?